# Get all fields defined in a bundle

Tags: 8, entities

In Drupal 7, to get all fields used in a content type, I use the following code.

```
$fields = field_info_instances('node', 'article');
```

What is the equivalent for Drupal 8?

Comment: Are you working with an entity? If so: `$fields = $entity->getFieldDefinitions();` will do it. I'm not sure what the equivalent of `field_info_instances()` is, [`FieldStorageConfig`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21src%21Entity%21FieldStorageConfig.php/class/FieldStorageConfig/8) doesn't appear to have one

Comment: No I just want to alter the node_type_edit_form and add a list of fields defined by the node type in the form. So the type of the node is the only argument I have. So I thought function like field_info_instances might help.

Comment: @Clive: can I create an entity object using the entity type name. There is a function NodeType::load('article') which creates object for node types.

Comment: `\Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'article')` did the job clive :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I achieved it using `getFieldDefinitions()` defined in `Class EntityManager`. So in order get all fields used in a particular bundle, Here is a way:

```
$bundle_fields = \Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'article');
```

Though the above `$bundle_fields` also contains `nid, uuid, revisions, langcode, etc` as fields. So to get an accurate output I did something like this:

```
  $entity_type_id = 'node';
  $bundle = 'article';
  foreach (\Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldDefinitions($entity_type_id, $bundle) as $field_name => $field_definition) {
    if (!empty($field_definition->getTargetBundle())) {
      $bundleFields[$entity_type_id][$field_name]['type'] = $field_definition->getType();
      $bundleFields[$entity_type_id][$field_name]['label'] = $field_definition->getLabel();
    }
  }
```

Comment: This works, however entityManager is deprecated. The comment above the function definition says use entityTypeManager or if the method is not implemented (getFieldDefinitions is not) _"see the deprecated \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager to find the correct interface or service."_ I don't understand this comment. Where can I look to find the correct function to use?

Comment: To filter out the base fields (`nid, uuid, revisions, langcode, etc`) you can do ```if($field->getFieldStorageDefinition()->isBaseField() == FALSE)```

Comment: Is there a way to get the Field Definitions to all types of content types not just one?

Comment: @leon.nk yes <code>if($field->getFieldStorageDefinition()->isBaseField() == FALSE)</code>that's more precise than <code>if (!empty($field_definition->getTargetBundle()))</code> to filter out base fields.

Comment: In case of a list with key|values how can I get the values from that field?

Comment: @leon.nk I used `if (!method_exists(get_class($field_definition), 'isBaseField') || !$field_definition->isBaseField())`. Which is safer because not every class may have that method implimented to call.

Comment: Use `\Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')` instead of `\Drupal::entityManager()`

Answer (score 55):

EntityManager is deprecated moving forward.  The following can be used instead:

```
$entityFieldManager = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager');
$fields = $entityFieldManager->getFieldDefinitions($entity_type, $bundle);
```

Whereas `$entity_type` can be `'node'` and `$bundle` can be `'article'`

Comment: Is there any way to get only cck field list?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now.

Comment: this does not work for nested paragraph fields , does it ?

Answer (score 11):

EntityManager is deprecated and I used the next code. I added to Controller class:

```php
/**
 * The entity field manager.
 *
 * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager
 */
protected $entityFieldManager;
    
/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager $entity_field_manager
 *   The entity field manager.
 */
public function __construct(EntityFieldManager $entity_field_manager) {
  $this->entityFieldManager = $entity_field_manager;
}
    
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
  return new static(
    $container->get('entity_field.manager')
  );
}

// Here some your functions

/**
 * Build table rows.
 */
protected function buildRows() {
  $entity_type_id = 'node';
  $bundle = 'article';
  $fields = $this->entityFieldManager->getFieldDefinitions($entity_type_id, $bundle);
  
  foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field_definition) {
    if (!empty($field_definition->getTargetBundle())) {               
      $listFields[$field_name]['type'] = $field_definition->getType();
      $listFields[$field_name]['label'] = $field_definition->getLabel();                  
    }
  }

  $rows = [];
  foreach ($listFields as $field_name => $info) {
    $rows[] = $this->buildRow($info, $field_name);
  }

  return $rows;
}
```

https://www.drupal.org/node/2549139 is what helped me

Comment: Some tips:
In constructors (and in general) use always interfaces. Most of the drupal service implementations have a well defined interfaces.

Comment: In case of a list with key|values how can I get the values from that field?