# How to get the "field" value of config entity, with bundles, that is defined in a bundle while creating content

Tags: 8

I am creating a custom entity (WebsiteType) with bundles (Website), where I want to define a URL, among other configurations, that all content in a given bundle should inherit.

I created the fields in the config entity type and managed to show and save these fields while creating a new bundle. Nevertheless, I couldn't manage to get these values in HOOK_entity_presave.

here is a sample of the code:

src/Entity/WebsiteType

Notation:

```
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "label" = "label",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *     "service_endpoint_url" = "service_endpoint_url",
```

Class:

```
class WebsiteType extends ConfigEntityBundleBase implements WebsiteTypeInterface {
  /**
   * The Website type Service Endpoint URL.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $service_endpoint_url;

}

 /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getServiceUrl() {
    return $this->service_endpoint_url;
  }
```

WebsiteTypeForm:

```
public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form = parent::form($form, $form_state);

  $website_type = $this->entity;

  $form['endpoint_settings']['service_endpoint_url'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $this->t('Argir Endpoint URL'),
    '#maxlength' => 255,
    '#description' => $this->t("The location of your service."),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => $website_type->getServiceUrl(),
    '#attributes' => [
      'placeholder' => $this->t('https://XXXXX.com'),
    ],
  ];
}
```

WebsiteTypeInterface:

```
interface WebsiteTypeInterface extends ConfigEntityInterface {

  public function getServiceUrl();
}
```

I followed the documentation of Drupal of Entity API

Checked the answer here: [enter link description here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161293/get-all-fields-defined-in-a-bundle)

also went through this outstanding tutorial: [enter link description here](https://www.daggerhart.com/drupal-8-practical-content-entity-bundles/)

Tried to work with EntityTypeManager

All of that with no luck. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

While creating content, HOOK_entity_presave() is called for the content entity and you can access only content fields. One of these content entity fields is a reference field to the bundle config entity, usually named `bundle`. Use this field to get the config entity via the magic property `entity` and get the config field value via the method you have defined in `WebsiteTypeInterface`:

```
$url = $entity->bundle->entity->getServiceUrl();
```

A more generic way when you don't know the bundle field name or the code should work for all entity types:

```
$bundle_field_name = $entity->getEntityType()->getKey('bundle');
if (!empty($bundle_field_name)) {
  $bundle_config = $entity->get($bundle_field_name)->entity;
  if ($bundle_config instanceof \Drupal\mymodule\Entity\WebsiteTypeInterface) {
    $url = $bundle_config->getServiceUrl();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks 4k4 for the fast response. I tried it but it didn't work `Error: Call to a member function getServiceUrl() on null in aegir_websites_manager_entity_presave()` here is the Hook: `function MY_MODULE_entity_presave(EntityInterface $entity){
  $url = $entity->bundle->entity->getServiceUrl();
}` What do you think?

Comment: You have to check the entity type or use hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave. Not all entity types have bundles.

Comment: I tried the hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave and still getting the same error. I am sure the entity has bundles. Is there anything else I can try? Thanks for the support 4k4

Comment: I've suggested a shortcut, if you know the bundle field. I add a more generic way to the answer.

Comment: Thanks again. the bundle field name "service_endpoint_url"

Comment: `$bundle_field_name` in my code example is the field in the content entity referencing the bundle, not a field in the bundle itself.

Comment: Many thanks man. It's working like a charm