# How to get fields definitions of a vocabulary in drupal 8/9?

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

I needed the field list related a vocabulary item.I was able to list the fields related to a content type by using like this:

```
\Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'article');
```

But I can't find a way for the vocabulary items.

Comment: What have you tried for taxonomies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\Drupal::entityManager()` is deprecated, instead you should use `\Drupal::entityTypeManager`. From [the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityManager/8.2.x):

> Deprecated in Drupal 8.0.0 and will be removed before Drupal 9.0.0. Use \Drupal::entityTypeManager() instead in most cases. If the needed method is not on \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface, see the deprecated \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager to find the correct interface or service.

This is especially relevant here as the [`getFieldDefinitions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManager.php/function/EntityFieldManager%3A%3AgetFieldDefinitions/8.8.x) method has moved to a different service, [`entity_field.manager`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManager.php/class/EntityFieldManager/8.8.x).

With all of this said, you can use the same method to get taxonomy term fields as any other bundle. As documented in [this related answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/210704/48114):

```
$entity_type_id = 'taxonomy_term';
$bundle = 'article_tags';

// Load the field definitions for any bundle.
$my_bundle_fields = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')
  ->getFieldDefinitions($entity_type_id, $bundle);
```